# Clarinet trilling over the break

Tags: clarinet, trills

I am practicing Capriccio Espagnol by Nikolai Rimsky-Korsakov Arr. by Richard Meyer, and there is a trill that I've looked at 100 times and I am absolutely sure it goes over the break from A to B. Whenever I do it, it doesn't sound like I'm playing a trill, more like sloppy triplets. Does anyone have a video of someone playing this trill? And, do you have any tips for me? I only have two years of experience playing clarinet. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what the top two side keys are for. From a throat A, adding the top side key results in a B.