# Clarinet A/B trill with fuller sound

Tags: fingering, tone, clarinet, trills

I am trying to do a trill over the break between the Clarion and Chalumeau registers, between A and B.

You are meant to add the upper side key to the A, see e.g. [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/61837/clarinet-trilling-over-the-break).

> This is what the top two side keys are for. From a throat A, adding
>   the top side key results in a B.

The B does not have a very full sound. Is there a way to add more to it using the embouchure or something? Or does it just sound a bit weaker than trying to trill the usual way?

Comment: Trill fingerings are a compromise.  They are intended to be fast and easy, but you don't (normally) hold the note long enough to notice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct that the side-key trill is not a very good sound.  There is really no way to produce a better trill for that one combo of notes.  We all live with it.

Comment: It is Bach, Italian concerto I am playing (2nd movement). The end of the first passage after about 1min playing has an important A/B till, which is slow and relaxed. But if done properly it sounds ok.

Answer (score 3):

I don't personally find it a less "full"  sound - it just has a different quality to B as the lowest note in the upper register - not surprisingly given the very different acoustic properties of the two notes. I sometimes use that side B as a melody note in its own right, as it is better matched to A and Bb below it. It's a bit "darker" than the low end of the clarion.

You do need a different level of support to make sure it isn't a bit flat. And make sure all the toneholes are clean and not filled with gunk.

Comment: Also, I am noticing that if a press the trill key too hard, it presses the next trill key, adding extra sharpness. It sounds much nice when I trill it lightly.

Comment: @AlexanderKartun-Giles  If that happens, you need to adjust the "stop" pad under the trill key.  That overlap should not occur.